# How to modify a yarl.URL object?

Tags: python, url, python-requests, python-3.6

I am trying to update the path of a relative url using python requests. My `request.rel_url` object (`datatype = <class 'yarl.URL'>`) has the following value:

```
/date/v6/cal?week=three&day=mon
```

I would like to replace `'v6'` here with `'v7'` so that my updated URL is:

```
/date/v7/cal?week=three&day=mon
```

I have used string replace in python but looks like we cannot use that here with a `yarl.URL` object.

Any suggestions on how I can update this URL object, while retaining its datatype?

Comment: How is your `request.rel_url` object defined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert it to a string, then use the `str.replace` method:

```
print(str(your_object).replace('v6', 'v7'))
```

After you have the url, you can convert it back to a `yarl.URL` object.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, this would work; wondering if there is a native way to replace/update a path in URL object directly without intermediate string conversion?

Comment: @D.prd There is. The answer by _samepoi_ shows it.

Comment: Raw string replacement has so many edge cases that would fail. This seems to completely miss the point of yarl.

Answer (score 3):

The yarl module has various `with_`-methods to modify a `URL`. (see [docs](https://yarl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#yarl.URL.with_path))

Take a look at this example:

```py
from yarl import URL

url = URL('/date/v6/cal?week=three&day=mon')
new_url = url.with_path('/date/v7/cal').with_query(url.query)

print(new_url)  # /date/v7/cal?week=three&day=mon
```